# Why can't I copy a folder from remote server to local with this command?

Tags: scp, linux-terminal

I'm logged into my remote server as root, I want to copy a folder to my local machine. What is wrong with my code below please ?

```
scp -r myfolder 12.34.56.789/c/copyofmyfolder
```

12.34.56.789 is my local machine's IP address. I keep getting the message :

```
cp: cannot create directory '12.34.56.789/c/copyofmyfolder': No such file or directory
```

I can see clearly on my local machine that `copyofmyfolder` exists, in the correct location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is a missing `:`.

You are copying a filename on your local machine starting with the name 12.34.56.789.

You probably intended `scp -r myfolder 12.34.56.789:/c/copyofmyfolder`
(notice the IP or hostname followed by `:`)

Comment: That's much better, that message is gone, but now I get : `ssh: connect to host 12.34.56.789 port 22: Connection timed out lost connection` do I need to have ssh installed to do this transfer?No other way?

Comment: You need a client on one side and something to accept the connection on the other side. If the receiving side was a BSD or linux I would say you needed to make sure sshd was running. On Windows: no idea.

Comment: Yes, I run on Windows. I am using Cygwin, which I believe emulates a Linux environment.

Comment: Possible relevant reading: http://serverfault.com/questions/648855/is-iis-sftp-natively-supported-by-windows-server-2012-r2/648865#648865